# How to show the rowGroup count in a collapsed DT in R Shiny?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, datatables, dt

I'm looking at this previous question [Collapse rowGroup Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59896704/collapse-rowgroup-shiny) and the solution provided.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
ui <- fluidPage(# Application title
  titlePanel("Collapse/Expand table"),
  mainPanel(DTOutput("my_table")))

callback_js <- JS(
    "table.on('click', 'tr.dtrg-group', function () {",
    "  var rowsCollapse = $(this).nextUntil('.dtrg-group');",
    "  $(rowsCollapse).toggleClass('hidden');",
    "});",
    "table.one('init', () => $('#my_table .dtrg-group').trigger('click'))"
  )

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$my_table <- DT::renderDT({
    datatable(
      mtcars[1:15, 1:5],
      extensions = 'RowGroup',
      options = list(rowGroup = list(dataSrc = 2), pageLength = 20),
      callback = callback_js,
      selection = 'none'
    )
  })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I managed to enhance the JS such that the wakeup view of this table is collapsed. Data in this example is collapsed based off dataSrc = 2 that corresponds to the 2nd column of the mtcards table, that is, the 'cyl' column. What I need: I would need to be able to see the count of cars for each cyl category when the table is collapsed. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one example where the count of each category is written into the collapsed row groups by editing the corresponding `innerHTML`. You can get this by adding the following `JS` to your callback.

```
table.on('init', () => $('#my_table .dtrg-group').each(function(i, obj) {
    var grpcount = $(this).nextUntil('.dtrg-group').length.toString();
    this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace('</th>', ', count: ' + grpcount + '</th>');
}));"
```

[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(# Application title
    titlePanel("Collapse/Expand table"),
    mainPanel(DTOutput("my_table")))

callback_js <- JS(
    "table.on('click', 'tr.dtrg-group', function () {",
    "  var rowsCollapse = $(this).nextUntil('.dtrg-group');",
    "  $(rowsCollapse).toggleClass('hidden');",
    "});",
    "table.one('init', () => $('#my_table .dtrg-group').trigger('click'))",
    "table.on('init', () => $('#my_table .dtrg-group').each(function(i, obj) {",
    "    var grpcount = $(this).nextUntil('.dtrg-group').length.toString();",
    "    this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace('</th>', ', count: ' + grpcount + '</th>');",
    "}));"
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$my_table <- DT::renderDT({
        datatable(
            mtcars[1:15, 1:5],
            extensions = 'RowGroup',
            options = list(
                rowGroup = list(dataSrc = 2),
                pageLength = 20
            ),
            callback = callback_js,
            selection = 'none'
        )
    })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: This is great! By the way, would you also know if it's possible to add an average of one of the columns? (sorry for the late response, I was out for paternity leave)

Comment: Yes, this should be possible. I will have a look at it later.

Comment: Okay, it's maybe not very easy. You may want to ask a follow-up question for this ...

Comment: Does it mean creating a new question? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I would recommend this.